# Trigger Error, Doesn't show Raiserror Message

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger that I am testing to change a value in the column `CurrentFlag` in the  `AdventureWorksDW2014` database.

This trigger can allow me execute an update query, if the value of `CurrentFlag` is 0 or 1, if I execute any of these queries:

```
UPDATE DIMEMPLOYEES 
SET CURRENTFLAG = 0 
WHERE EMPLOYEEKEY = 1 

UPDATE DIMEMPLOYEES 
SET CURRENTFLAG = 1 
WHERE EMPLOYEEKEY = 1
```

So if both conditions are met, a message should appear on the console that says something like this: `PRINT 'VALUE UPDATED'`, so if those conditions are not met, a message like this should be the same:

```
PRINT 'VALUE ERROR CANNOT BE UPDATED, IS NOT WITHIN THE PARAMETERS ALLOWED'
```

I have this trigger that does something similar but I have not been able to try to adapt it. This is the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER NOUPDATE 
ON DIMEMPLOYEE
FOR UPDATE
AS
    IF UPDATE(CURRENTFLAG) 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE DimEmployee 
        SET CurrentFlag = H.CURRENTFLAG
        FROM DimEmployee J 
        INNER JOIN inserted H ON J.CurrentFlag = H.CurrentFlag
        WHERE H.CurrentFlag <= 1

        RAISERROR('VALUE UPDATED.', 10, 1)
    END

    BEGIN
        UPDATE DimEmployee 
        SET CurrentFlag = H. CURRENTFLAG
        FROM DimEmployee J 
        INNER JOIN inserted H ON J.CurrentFlag = H.CurrentFlag
        WHERE H.CurrentFlag > 1

        RAISERROR('VALUE ERROR CANNOT BE UPDATED, IS NOT WITHIN THE PARAMETERS ALLOWED', 10, 1)
    END          
GO
```

Comment: When you say "show on the screen" do you mean in app code or the SSMS messages tab? The `RAISERROR` specifies severity 10 so it is an informational/warning message and will not raise an error.

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes, it is a Warning Message, it Should Show on screen  applying the conditional structure.

Comment: Show on what screen? If you mean on an application screen, you'll need to handle the message according to the API you are using. It will not show by default. Also, the UPDATE statement will not change data since the inserted table has the rows after the update.

Comment: @DanGuzman or anyone can check that trigger? a little help here please.

Comment: It won't print to the console but you could write it to the error log via `WITH LOG`. Also, with an error of 10 or lower, the error is returned to the caller only if your error is in aTRY block. Or, just write this *log* to a log table.